Count gaps for a class & coupling class
I'd like to retrieve the results from my timetable where there are more than 3 consecutive gaps on a sigle day, for a class. I have managed to accomplish this for a solo class, but I'm unable to do it when combining with coupling classes.

Solo class = A class that represents itself, example "A", "B"
Coupling class = A class that represents 2 or more classes, example "A, B", "D, E, F"

When looking for consecutive gaps, I need to take into consideration that the class can be solo "A" or in a coupling "A, B"
My initial table structure:
CREATE TABLE classes (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
);  

INSERT INTO classes (name) 
VALUES 
    ('A'),
    ('B'),
    ('A, B');
    
CREATE TABLE classes_coupling (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  class_id INT,
  class_coupling_id 
);  
    
INSERT INTO classes_coupling (class_id, class_coupling_id) 
VALUES 
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2);  

My timetable table structure:
CREATE TABLE timetable (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  day_id INT,
  timeslot_id INT,
  class_id INT
);

--- class_id 1 = A 
--- class_id 2 = A, B

INSERT INTO timetable (day_id, timeslot_id, class_id) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, 2, 1),
    (1, 6, 1), --- Gap here, from 2 to 6 in class "A"
    (2, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (2, 4, 1),
    (3, 1, 1), --- From here to end gap shouldn't exist because the class_id = 2 is related with "A"
    (3, 2, 1), 
    (3, 3, 2), 
    (3, 4, 2), 
    (3, 7, 2), 
    (3, 8, 2), 
    (3, 9, 1);

Since I'm unable to tell that class_id = 2 is also related to class "A", the query shows 2 results:

Gap : day 1 : between 2 & 6
Gap : day 3 : between 2 to 9

My query to check if the class has gaps:
SELECT 
    day_id,
    class_id,
    MIN(timeslot_id) AS start_timeslot,
    MAX(next_timeslot_id) - 1 AS end_timeslot,
    MAX(next_timeslot_id) - MIN(timeslot_id) - 1 AS gap_size
FROM (
    SELECT 
        day_id,
        class_id,
        timeslot_id,
        LEAD(timeslot_id) OVER (PARTITION BY day_id, class_id ORDER BY timeslot_id) AS next_timeslot_id
    FROM 
        timetable
) AS subquery
WHERE 
    (next_timeslot_id - timeslot_id > 3 OR next_timeslot_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY 
    day_id, class_id, next_timeslot_id
HAVING 
    MAX(next_timeslot_id) - MIN(timeslot_id) > 3 AND class_id = 1
ORDER BY 
    day_id, class_id, start_timeslot;

In the end, I'm looking for the following simple output:
day_id | class_id 
1      | 1

Basically, classes grouped by day where they have 3 consecutive timeslots empty. How can I achieve this?

try like this...
relationships:
CREATE VIEW class_relationships AS
SELECT 
    c1.id AS primary_class_id,
    c1.name AS primary_class_name,
    c2.id AS coupled_class_id,
    c2.name AS coupled_class_name
FROM 
    classes c1
LEFT JOIN 
    classes_coupling cc ON c1.id = cc.class_id
LEFT JOIN 
    classes c2 ON cc.class_coupling_id = c2.id;


timetable with the primary class and coupled classes:
CREATE VIEW timetable_with_couplings AS
SELECT 
    t.day_id,
    t.timeslot_id,
    t.class_id,
    COALESCE(c.primary_class_id, t.class_id) AS primary_class_id
FROM 
    timetable t
LEFT JOIN 
    class_relationships c ON t.class_id = c.coupled_class_id
UNION
SELECT 
    t.day_id,
    t.timeslot_id,
    t.class_id,
    t.class_id AS primary_class_id
FROM 
    timetable t
WHERE 
    t.class_id NOT IN (SELECT coupled_class_id FROM class_relationships);


identify gaps:
WITH gaps AS (
    SELECT
        day_id,
        primary_class_id AS class_id,
        timeslot_id,
        LEAD(timeslot_id) OVER (PARTITION BY day_id, primary_class_id ORDER BY timeslot_id) AS next_timeslot_id
    FROM 
        timetable_with_couplings
),
filtered_gaps AS (
    SELECT
        day_id,
        class_id,
        MIN(timeslot_id) AS start_timeslot,
        MAX(next_timeslot_id) - 1 AS end_timeslot,
        MAX(next_timeslot_id) - MIN(timeslot_id) - 1 AS gap_size
    FROM 
        gaps
    WHERE 
        (next_timeslot_id - timeslot_id > 3 OR next_timeslot_id IS NULL)
    GROUP BY 
        day_id, class_id, next_timeslot_id
    HAVING 
        MAX(next_timeslot_id) - MIN(timeslot_id) > 3
)
SELECT 
    fg.day_id,
    fg.class_id
FROM 
    filtered_gaps fg
JOIN 
    classes c ON fg.class_id = c.id
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM classes_coupling cc 
        WHERE cc.class_id = fg.class_id
    )
ORDER BY 
    fg.day_id, fg.class_id;


There's a mistype I believe on c.primary_class_id which I think is cp.primary_class_id. However, now, it doesn't return any single class, it just returns the coupling class and the data is not correct. It's pointing out gaps where they don't exists.

Almost! it's working, but it's also showing the "coupling classes" in the returned results. Is there any way to avoid it? I'm only looking for the "solo classes".

@Linesofcode updated. try now

perfect, working as intended. I promise you that I'm gonna buy you a coffee once I implement this on the final project. Thank you !

One more question, what would you do to take into consideration the fact that this can be used by multiple subscriptions and that each subscription has it's own classes & timetable data? (SaaS related)

@Linesofcode I'm not expert, but to adapt this solution for a multi-tenant (SaaS) environment where each subscription has its own set of classes and timetable data, the following modifications need to be made:
1: Add Subscription ID to Tables: Ensure that all relevant tables (e.g., classes, timetable, classes_coupling) include a subscription_id column to distinguish data belonging to different subscriptions.
2: Modify Views and Queries: Incorporate the subscription_id in the views and queries to ensure data isolation and correct association of data per subscription.

Yes, I've come up with a similar solution, thanks. I'm also trying to see if I can convert your solution into stored procedures instead of views, to prevent views from constantly updating. I'm having a little more trouble here, do you think such thing is feasible?

@Linesofcode I never tried it, but to convert views into stored procedures, you can create a series of stored procedures that perform the necessary transformations and store the results into temporary or permanent tables. this approach would ensure that the computations are performed only when the stored procedures are executed, rather than being automatically updated whenever the underlying tables change

Exactly, that's what I'm aiming for. Thanks !
